# How to clear the input buffer with TTY set to raw mode using std::cin?

Tags: c++, posix, iostream, tty, termios

So I've used the termios library to put the terminal into raw mode, which allows me to do this:

```
int getch() {
  int ch;
  do {
    ch = cin.get();
  } while(cin.eof());
  return ch;
}
```

This waits for a single character to be ready in the input buffer and returns it.

But if I try to do this:

```
void clear_input_buffer() {
  char ch;
  while(!cin.fail()) {
    cin.get(ch);
  }
}
```

It goes into an endless loop.

What would be the appropriate way to clear the input buffer?  I've tried this:

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
```

But it also hangs.  I'd also like to do this using only iostreams or standard posix functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the usual:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```